# $\|x+y\|^2=\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2$ iff $x=cy$ with $c\gt0$?

Tags: linear-algebra

$ || \vec{x} + \vec{y} ||^2 = ||\vec{x}||^2 + ||\vec{y}||^2 $ iff $ \vec{x} = c\vec{y}$ with $ c>0$

Is this statement correct or not, if not not, please explain. I just started a self-study of Linear Algebra a week ago so my knowledge of it is not too big yet.

Comment: As written, no.  You've squared 2 out of the 3 terms.  Is that intentional?

Comment: Oh, no, not intentional sir, I edited it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$||\vec x+\vec y||^2 = (\vec x+\vec y)(\vec x+\vec y) = \vec x\vec x+2\vec x\vec y+\vec y\vec y=||\vec x||^2+||\vec y||^2+2\vec x\vec y$.
Thus equality holds iff $\vec x\vec y=0$, i.e. $\vec x$ and $\vec y$ are *orthogonal*.

Comment: So in particular, we *can't* allow $\vec x=c\vec y$ with $c>0$.

Comment: only if it's $L_2$ norm

Answer (score 4):

If $x = cy$, $c \geq 0$, you have $||x+y|| = ||x|| + ||y||$, *not* $||x+y||^2 = ||x||^2 + ||y||^2$. (BTW, if you have $c \leq 0$, you get $||x+y|| = \left|||x|| - ||y||\right|$)

This is because you then have (in the non-squared case, $c \geq 0$ again) $$
||x+y|| = ||x + cx|| = ||(1+c)x|| = (1+c)||x|| = ||x|| + c||x|| = ||x|| + ||cx|| = ||x|| + ||y||.$$

In the squared case with $c \geq 0$ you end up with $(1+c)^2||x||^2$ on the left side, and $(1+c^2)||x||^2$ on the right side, which is in general *not* the same.

To see *why* that is the case, look at these things geometrically. $||x+y||$ is the *length* of the vector $x+y$. Now, how does the length of two vectors behave if you add them? In general, the resulting length will be *smaller* than the individual lengths. If the vectors point in the same direction (which is what $x=cy$, $c \geq 0$ means), the resulting length *will* be the sum of the individual lengths, though.

If you add the *squares* of the lengths instead, the vetors have to be orthogonal (i.e., the angle between them has to be 90 degree). It works then because for an orthogonal triangle you have $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$ if $a$,$b$ and the lengths of the orthogonal sides, and $c$ is the length of the third side. Note that the third side if interpreted as a vector is the same as the sum of the two other sides, if also interpreted as vectors.

Comment: What you wrote is true if $c>0$. In general you have $\|(1+c)x\|=|1+c|\cdot\|x\|$ and $\|cx\|=|c|\cdot\|x\|$.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Ups, yeah, I was a bit sloppy there. Will edit to fix.